# Full height square element in android

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, landscape-portrait

I would like to have a square (same width as height) GridView fill the full height of the screen in landscape orientation. The Gridview is a chessboard (8 by 8 squares) with the xml:

```
<com.example.jens.jchess2.view.MyGridView
    android:id="@+id/chessboard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:numColumns="8"
    android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="0dp">
</com.example.jens.jchess2.view.MyGridView>
```

and the elements of the grid are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/square"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000080"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="0pt">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/square_background"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="0pt" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/piece"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:padding="0pt" />

</FrameLayout>
```

, where the ImageViews correspond to the squares and pieces (both from png images) of the board.

In the custom MyGridView I override onMeasure as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;


    if (width > height) {
        super.onMeasure(
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        );
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(width, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY)
        );
    }
}
```

which gives me a square GridView in both portrait and landscape orientation. In portrait mode it fills the full width and everything is fine. In landscape mode however it extends below the screen because the height (=width) of the GridView/board is too large. It is too large by the height of the toolbar and the height of the statusbar. How can I get the proper size for the GridView, i.e. screen height minus status bar height minus toolbar height?

Comment: make heightMeasureSpec equal to height of window ....

Answer (score 0):

Start with two versions of your layout file:

/res/layout/grid.xml

```
   ...

    <!-- full width -->
    <com.example.MyGridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ...
        />

   ...
```

/res/layout-land/grid.xml

```
   ...

    <!-- full height -->
    <com.example.MyGridView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        ...
        />

   ...
```

You probably already have something like this.

Now in your `onMeasure()` override, the `match_parent` dimension will have a `MeasureSpec` mode of `EXACTLY` and the `wrap_content` dimension will have a `MeasureSpec` mode of `AT_MOST`.  You can use this to achieve your desired layout.

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

    int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
    int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);


    if (widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY && heightMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        // portrait
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);

    } else if (heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY && widthMode == MeasureSpec.AT_MOST) {
        // landscape
        super.onMeasure(heightMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:  I found out that both modes can be AT_MOST depending on the `ViewGroup` container.   Please see my other answer for updated measuring code.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. I get only a single row of grid elements.

Comment: Is the `GridView` itself square?  If it is, then you may need to do something to get your item views to size differently.  If you could post your grid item layout XML that would help.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I posted the XML of the grid items above and also tried to clarify what my problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Ah. Now I see that this is for a game.

Sometimes it's better to have layouts and child views, but in most cases with game boards you are better off creating a single `View` subclass that represents the game view.

For instance, what if your users say they want the ability to pinch-zoom into one quadrant of the game board?  You can't do that with a `GridView`.

I whipped up a simple app to show you how this can work.  I simplified the `onMeasure()` code I posted before, and instead of a `GridView`, a single `View` subclass renders the game board.

The MainActivity simply sets up the content view.

/res/layout/activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.gameboard.MainActivity">

    <com.example.gameboard.GameBoardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

/res/layout-land/activity_main.xml:

Notice `match_parent` and `wrap_content` are switched for width and height.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.gameboard.MainActivity">

    <com.example.gameboard.GameBoardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

GameBoardView.java:

```
public class GameBoardView extends View {

    private Paint mPaint;

    public GameBoardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public GameBoardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public GameBoardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public GameBoardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        int width = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
        int size = Math.min(width, height);
        int sizeMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(size, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

        super.onMeasure(sizeMeasureSpec, sizeMeasureSpec);

        mPaint = new Paint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        int w = getWidth() / 8;
        int h = getHeight() / 8;

        for (int row = 0; row < 8; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < 8; col++) {
                // choose black or white depending on the square
                mPaint.setColor((row + col) % 2 == 0 ? 0xFFFFFFFF : 0xFF000000);
                canvas.drawRect(w * col, h * row, w * (col + 1), h * (row + 1), mPaint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm just drawing the squares right in the view.  Now, if I were making a chess game, I would also create a `Drawable` subclass that would take the game model and render it.  Having a separate `Drawable` for rendering the game makes it easy to scale to the correct size.  For example, your `Drawable` could render at a fixed constant size, then be scaled by the `View` subclass to fit.  The `View` subclass would function mostly as a controller, interpreting touch events and updating the game model.